# Flask-Admin Select2 allow duplicate model

Tags: flask-admin

With the default select2 drop down it removes the model from the list after I have added it, how do I allow the user to add the same model multiple times?

This looks like an issue with the select2 version where it does not allow multiple items of the same type to be selected.  So it is really configuring the UI for many to many relationships